# Why can't I request a specific function from an object?

Tags: node.js, function, discord.js

I'm programming my first project, a bot for discord made in discord.js, but I'm having a problem. My project has a folder of functions that follow this model (I will use this random number function as an example ):

```
module.exports.randomNumber = function (min, max) {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  return number;
}
```

My handler reads all the files and saves them in an object that is exported so that I can use them in my commands:

```
const fs = require("node:fs");

const functionsManager = {};

try {
  fs.readdir("./src/functions", (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      for (const file of files) {
        const functionName = file.replace(".js", "");

        functionsManager[functionName] = require(`../functions/${file}`);
      }
    }
  })

  module.exports = functionsManager;
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

When I require functions and save them in a variable, like this: `const functionsManager = require("...");` They work, however, when I try to request just a few, like this: `const { randomNumber, randomColor, ... } = require("...");` They don't work... The following error appears:

> Type Error: randomNumber (or any of the others functions) is not a functions

Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your export structure, you need to access the function through the object property when you import:

```js
const functionsManager = require("...");

// Now access functions like this
const randomNumber = functionsManager.randomNumber;
const randomColor = functionsManager.randomColor;
```

Either of these approaches should resolve the TypeError you're encountering. Choose the one that best fits your project structure and preferences.

Comment: In this case, if I don't want to maintain this export structure, what would I have to modify so that I could require the functions like this: { ..., ..., ... }?

Comment: @MagnumChaos You should try with Promise. Thanks
`// Import the functions using async/await
(async () => {
  try {
    const functionsManager = await require("...");

    // Destructure the functions
    const { randomNumber, randomColor } = functionsManager;

    // Now you can use the functions safely
    console.log(randomNumber());
    console.log(randomColor());
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend following this approach, because you'll have very difficulties to make this work.

You can configure your package.json with `"type": "module"`, and exporting yours functions in a file, this way:

```
export * from './function1'
export * from './function2'
export * from './function3'
```

And when you need import your functions, just do it:

```
import { function1 } from './file-with-exports'
```